# Set a label value for a checkbox helper in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am developping an asp.net mvc application.

I have a viewmodel :

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public bool IsActive {get;set;}
}
```

And I have the associated razor view :

```
<span>@Html.CheckBoxFor(d => d.IsActive)</span>
```

The problem with this is that I have only the `checkbox` in my view without any `label`, I would like to know if it's possible to indicate a `label` in the `CheckBoxFor` parameter or by adding an attribute on my property in the ViewModel.

Comment: Add `@Html.LabelFor(d => d.IsActive)` to your view

Comment: Or add `[Display(Name = "Sample Label Text"]   public bool IsActive {get;set;}` above class property in viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Data Annotations. Add this at the top of your ViewModel class definition

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

Add `[Display(Name = "Active")]` above the `IsActive` property

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Active")]
    public bool IsActive {get;set;}
}
```

and add `@Html.LabelFor(d => d.IsActive)` in your view

```
@Html.LabelFor(d => d.IsActive)<span>@Html.CheckBoxFor(d => d.IsActive)</span>
```

which will render `<label for="IsActive">Active</label>` before the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below :

Add below namespace in your ViewModel

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

Then use `[Display(Name="Sample Label Text")]` above class property.

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Sample Label Text")]
    public bool IsActive {get;set;}
}
```

At last use `@Html.LabelFor` to render it

```
<span>@Html.LabelFor(d => d.IsActive)</span>
<span>@Html.CheckBoxFor(d => d.IsActive)</span>
```